# Shuffling a list in python

Tags: python

I have a python list object that has the following list,

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 0, 4].
```

I wanted to shuffle it with the following code:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(a)
```

But what's meaning of below code:

```
a[::-1]
[4, 0, 3, 2, 1] # output
```

I know slice indices of python. But I've never seen above form before. So,I don't understand why that works?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not shuffling - that is reversing.

Comment: See the docs for [extended slice](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) notation.

Comment: It's my fault. I've had it,thanks for everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `mylist[::-1]` syntax, as asked, reverses a list. It does **NOT** shuffle the list.

[Python Extended Slice Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices)

> Negative values also work to make a copy of the same list in reverse
>   order:

```
>>> L[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```